# Notepad++ - Use regex to find and replace certain whitespaces with commas

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, whitespace

This is my data.

```
256 heavy we,ambidext
498 lockpick (none)
657 teaching teaching
112 night op auto wea
295 stealthy on roof
214 teaching electron
746 night op teaching
```

How would I put commas in all of the spaces that are below the comma in the first line?  Example:

```
256 heavy we,ambidext
498 lockpick,(none)
657 teaching,teaching
112 night op,auto wea
295 stealthy,on roof 
214 teaching,electron
746 night op,teaching
```

Seems like it should be simple.  I searched for an answer for a while without any luck.  Thanks for the help!

Thanks for the replies.  There are returns (show up in N++ as CRLF) at the end of each line.  There's no way to use regex to say something like: Find a return (one could replace the returns with some other characters if that would help) and then find a space between 7 and 10 characters *back* from the return and change it to a comma?

I ended up using the column select function in Notepad++ (hold alt and then use mouse to select) and after that I used the TextFX Find/Replace plugin inside my selection to change the spaces.  That worked pretty well.  Thanks!

Comment: it couldn't be done through regex..

Comment: Can you do it in two steps? I.e., first determine the position of the first comma, then construct a regex that will replace all spaces at that position with commas in all the following lines?

Comment: I do not think it is so simple you assume to be. You want that a feature in a line (a comma) to be extended to the next lines by means of NotePad++ regular expressions. My knowledge about Notepad++ is not deep as other programs' but the regular expressions in the most of the tools I know are applied line by line. In other words, a regular expression matching a blank character does not know anything about a comma in other line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to build a regex to achieve you goal, since there is no rule for the requirement, sometimes one word, some times more words.

However, if you say the input text format is exactly same as your example, you can add the `,` to certain column. In fact that is the only rule/pattern I found in your text, then you can do it with regex, like

replace `^(.{12})\s`  with `\1,`

then you got the output.

P.S. with **better** :-)  editor like vim, you can just `Ctrl-V` your column, then `r,` done.

Comment: Looks like we both came to the same result :). +1 for having a better explanation! ;)

Comment: @Kent You can do column editing in N++ as well, and that mode is definitely easier.

Comment: @Jerry okay ... good to know it, thx. I would know better about notepad++, if I got more chance to use it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Keep <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed
2. click mouse left button and drag from the first position (line 2, col 13) until the last line
3. press <kbd>,</kbd>

And you're done.

Comment: This worked really well too!  In fact, this was the easiest.  Thanks!

Comment: This function is really cool. Maybe you should add that you must release [Alt] before point 3.